# How to save my dtm generated from LAS point cloud as tiff file in lidR package?

Tags: point-clouds, las, lidr

I am trying to save the dtm generated using `plot` command. The `dtm` has been generated from las using lidR using this code

```r
dtm1_tin <- rasterize_terrain(las1, res = 1, algorithm = tin())
plot_dtm3d(dtm1_tin, bg = "white")
 
# Trying to save my plot using
savePlot("dtm1_tin", type = "tiff", device = dev.cur(), restoreConsole = TRUE)
#> Error in savePlot("dtm1_tin", type = "tiff", device = dev.cur(), restoreConsole = TRUE) : 
no such device
```

Comment: Do you want to save the raster or do you want to save an image of the 3D rendering? This is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should be able to use the generic `terra::writeRaster` with your `dtm1_tin` object.

So:

```
terra::writeRaster(dtm1_tin, "your_data_dir/your_file_name.tif", filetype = "GTiff", overwrite = TRUE)
```